# How to get avatar in on_member_join using python discord bot?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Sir,

I want to get avatar of member in `on_member_join` using python discord bot as we know that it only takes member I can't use ctx so how can I get the avatar image. This is required because I want to make welcome embeds like mee6 or Koya. Can anyone help me to solve this problem

we know ctx is required to get avatar
`avatmember = ctx.author await ctx.send(avatmember.avatar.url)`
if we write it as
 `await channel.send(member.avatar.url)`  `
it shows

`await channel.send(member.avatar.url) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'`

My code

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
robota = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents, help_command=None)
clients = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@robota.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = robota.get_channel(Channel_ID)
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Welcome!",description=f"{member.mention} Just Joined")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

[image]

Comment: No, you don't need [ctx](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) for everything. An [on_member_join](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_join) event quite literally takes the member object that you can use. Try reading the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_member_join)

Comment: yes sir I have use `member.avatar.url` but it showing me error `File "d:\Code\python projects\Robota\robota.py", line 52, in on_member_join embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url'`

Comment: have you tried to print the member?

Comment: yes it print my discord id (ABCD#1234) I am not giving my original id for my account privacy

Comment: Sir, I got my answer my discord profile has no avatar and I was just trying to get the default discord avatar. It takes the default avatar as null. then when I give an image to the profile it shows the image. Sir, is there any way to get the default avatar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you pass `member` when declaring the function?

If you want to create a welcome message with member avatar then you can use something like this -

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = bot.get_channel(WELCOME_CHANNEL_ID)
    await channel.send("Welcome!")

    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Welcome to the server, {member.name}!")
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)

    await channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: ` File "d:\Code\python projects\Robota\robota.py", line 52, in on_member_join
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=member.avatar.url)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'url' `

it gives me this error

Comment: Strange, it works for me

Comment: I think they change something in the new update of discord.py

Comment: Did you enable members intents?

Comment: yes i have given screenshot of that in my question

Comment: `intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True
robota = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents, help_command=None)
clients = discord.Client(intents=intents)` and i had also did this

Comment: Sir, I got my answer my discord profile has no avatar and I was just trying to get the default discord avatar. It takes the default avatar as null. then when I give an image to the profile it shows the image. Sir, is there any way to get the default avatar?

Comment: I don't think you can get the default avatars cause it is just a none value.